# Multiple Events, Independence and Conditional Independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, elementary-set-theory, probability-distributions

Hope you are doing well.

I found an online resource from MIT that I found valuable. But, it is just notes with scenarios but no answers.[image]

In particular,

I am focused on the bottom: "If we don't know which coin it is, are the tosses independent?".

P(toss 11 = H) should be 1/2 because we don't which coin it is and we have no other information. But what is the formal proof for it?

The
P(toss 11 = H |first 10 tosses are H) appear dependent as we can infer from the new information that since the first 10 tosses are H, the coin in question is Coin A. Again, is there a formal proof or mathematical way to think about it?

Comment: This is a routine Bayes' Theorem problem.  Obviously the tosses are not independent since we get information from prior tosses which changes our estimate of the probability in question.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. Beliefs changing because of new information is a key part of deciphering the independence/dependence (property) of events? If things change, clearly there is dependence. If they do not, independent.

Comment: @lulu But I would love to see a formal proof/example for both scenarios listed near the bottom.

Comment: Sure.  More simply, if events $E_1, E_2$ are independent 
 then $P(E_1\,|\,E_2)=P(E_1)$.  Letting $E_1$ be the event "The $11^{th}$ toss is $H$" and $E_2$ be "the first $10$ tosses were $H$" it is clear that $P(E_1\,|\,E_2)\neq P(E_1)$.

Comment: As I said, the formal proof is just Bayes' Theorem.  The posted solution from @herbsteinberg is fine

Comment: @lulu Ah, thank you. How about this one P(toss 11 = H) ?

Comment: That's just $\frac 12$, same as any of the other tosses.  With no information to tell you which coin you have, the probability is $\frac 12\times (.1+.9)=\frac 12$.

Comment: @lulu But why is the 0.1 and .9 even required? Isn't it just P(x) = 1/2 ?

Comment: No.  There is a $.5$ chance you get the $.9$ coin and a $.5$ chance you get the $.1$ coin.  It just happens that $.9+.1=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The law of total probability is invoked in the 2nd and 7th lines below:
$$P(11=H)\\=P(11=H|A)P(A)+P(11=H|B)P(B)\\=0.9\times0.5+0.1\times0.5\\=0.5.$$
$$P(11=H|\text{first 10 tosses are heads})\\=\frac{P(\text{first 11 tosses are heads})}{P(\text{first 10 tosses are heads})}\\=\frac{P(\text{first 11 tosses are heads}|A)P(A)+P(\text{first 11 tosses are heads}|B)P(B)}{P(\text{first 10 tosses are heads}|A)P(A)+P(\text{first 10 tosses are heads}|B)P(B)}\\=\frac{0.9^{11}\times0.5+0.1^{11}\times0.5}{0.9^{10}\times0.5+0.1^{10}\times0.5}\\=0.900$$
Since these two values differ, the first $10$ tosses being Heads, and the $11$th toss being Head, are dependent events. Thus, the $11$ tosses/trials are **not mutually independent**.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I wanted to understand what law was formally invoked. The Law of total probability made sense but I couldn't quite put it together.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of 10 heads in a row for coin A is $P_A=(.9)^{10}$ while for coin B the probability is $P_B=(.1)^{10}$.  The probability of heads on the next toss is then $.9\frac{P_A}{P_A+P_B}+.1\frac{P_B}{P_A+P_B}$.